# rest api calling lambda function , terraform deployment

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am having problems with setting up in terraform the rest api to call lambda function. I am missing something because when I deploy the lambda function from terraform and make a rest api manually from aws console with the same configuration (checked the console configuration 5 times already and it is the same as the one deployed with terraform ) . So when I deploy with terraform I get { "message": "Internal server error"} response . below my terraform code for lambda, rest api and ham . any idea what I am missing from the terraform conf . pretty sure that I am missing something at the rest api section ...

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "search_api" {
  name = "search_api"
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "search_api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "search"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "search_api" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.search_api.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.search_api.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.search_api.http_method
  status_code = "200"

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = null
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "search_api" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.search_api.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.search_api.http_method
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambda_search_py.invoke_arn
  credentials = aws_iam_role.search_py_lambda_execution.arn

  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode(
      {
        name = "$input.params('name')"
    })
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.lambda_search_py]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "search_api" {
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.search_api.http_method
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.search_api.id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.search_api
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "search_api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.id
  stage_name  = "test"

  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_integration.search_api]
}

output "search_api_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.search_api.invoke_url
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_search_py" {
  function_name    = "SearchField"
  s3_bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.lambda.id
  s3_key           = aws_s3_object.s3_search_py.key
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.data_lambda_search_py.output_base64sha256
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs.subnet_main_prv1a_id, data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs.subnet_main_prv2b_id]
    security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs.secgrp_ec2_id]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_search_py" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_search_py.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.search_api.execution_arn}/*/GET/search"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Sid    = ""
      Principal = {
        Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AWSLambda_FullAccess" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "search_py_lambda_execution" {
  name = "lambda_execution"
  
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
  
resource "aws_iam_policy" "search_py_lambda_execution" {
  name = "search_py_lambda_execution"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "search_py_lambda_execution1" {
  role = aws_iam_role.search_py_lambda_execution.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.search_py_lambda_execution.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" {
  role = aws_iam_role.search_py_lambda_execution.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess"
}
```

I am getting internal server error and I should get response from the lambda function when I call the rest api . if I create only the rest api from Amazon console then it is working

Comment: For Lambda I think you might need to use `integration_http_method = "POST"` and `type = "AWS_PROXY"`.

Comment: Is this a permissions issue? Do you have AWS credentials with correct permissions in TF?

Comment: @LHWizard the aws credentials are ok I can deploy to terraform my api gw and all the necesarry

Comment: I enabled logging and I came up with the below,but don't know what I am missing with access issue as when deploying the same thing from aws console works

(e1770769-c366-4097-b301-446d82d15437) Endpoint response body before transformations: <AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message></AccessDeniedException>
(e1770769-c366-4097-b301-446d82d15437) Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda request id: adf1a992-6ca6-4974-b0e8-d7163cd68910
(e1770769-c366-4097-b301-446d82d15437) Execution failed due to configuration error:

Comment: @MarkoE thx for the suggestion , I put post as the integration and it worked and for type I did not want to use proxy integration so I left it AWS . it is working now so the solution was to use integration_http_method = "POST"

Answer (score 0):

used integration_http_method = "POST" and it worked , thanks to Marko E for suggesting that